# Suppress the glossary expansion at first occurrence

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to generate the glossary in my report.

However, I am using the entries first time in a Table where it is expanding in the form `<item>(Description)`.

I would like to suppress the expansion where I do not find it necessary for the expansion even though it is the first occurance.

I am using `\gls{<label>}`. Any idea how to do it?

Currently, as a solution, I am just using the abbreviations in the table without the reference to glossary.

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) of your code.

Answer (score 20):

Simply use `\glsunset{<label>}` or `\glsunsetall` before you reference an acronym the first time. Furthermore, use `\glsreset{<label>}` or `\glsresetall` to re-enable full acronym expansion afterwards. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{OA}{OA}{One Acronym}
\newacronym{TA}{TA}{Two Acronyms}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\glsunsetall
\gls{OA}, \gls{TA}\\
\glsresetall
\gls{OA}, \gls{TA}\\
\gls{OA}, \gls{TA}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend `\acrshort{label}` which will only print the abbreviation of the acronym, even if it is the first occurrence.

Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{NFL}{NFL}{National Football League}

\begin{document}

First use: \acrshort{NFL}

Second use: \gls{NFL}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect solution for use in captions and tables as it expands the acronym when used later on in the main text.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `\gls{<label>}` you could use `\glsdisp{<label>}{<text>}` to display `<text>`. A little example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{am}{A.M.}{Ante Meridiem}
\newacronym{pm}{P.M.}{Post Meridiem}

\begin{document}

First use: \glsdisp{am}{A.M.} \gls{pm}

Second use: \gls{am} \gls{pm}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `glossaries` package offers several options for this directly. See the User manual for `v3.01`, Section 13. For example, if you pass the package option `footnote`, the expansion will occur in a footnote rather than (between braces).

For more advanced options, look into Section 13.3, "Defining A Custom Acronym Style".

To get nothing at all, I added to my preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
name={\the\glsshorttok},%
description={\the\glslongtok},%
text={\the\glsshorttok},%
plural={\the\glsshorttok}\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix%
}
\renewcommand*{\SetCustomDisplayStyle}[1]{%
\defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{##1##4}
\defglsdisplay[#1]{##1##4}}
\SetCustomStyle
```

A full working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\author{Gerrit Holl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
name={\the\glsshorttok},%
description={\the\glslongtok},%
text={\the\glsshorttok},%
plural={\the\glsshorttok}\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix%
}
\renewcommand*{\SetCustomDisplayStyle}[1]{%
\defglsdisplayfirst[#1]{##1##4}
\defglsdisplay[#1]{##1##4}}
\SetCustomStyle
\newacronym{NPP}{NPP}{National Partnership Program}
\newacronym{EOS}{EOS}{Earth Observing System}
\newacronym{POES}{POES}{Polar Orbiting Environmental Satellites}
\newacronym{NASA}{NASA}{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}
\begin{document}
\gls{NPP} is a bridge from \gls{EOS}, \gls{POES} to the next generation of
\gls{NASA} satellites.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```