# How to tweak expansion of glossary entry in section/chapter title and ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

I'm using `glossaries` to generate my acronyms. Sometimes the first definition of the acronym is placed in a section or chapter title. When I generate the ToC, then obviously that will become the first occurrence and will be expanded, but the acronym in the tile will not. Is it possible to have them expand either in both places or only in the tile, not the ToC? I'd like a general solution, meaning that I don't want to manually reset the glossary before the title where the acronym appears.

Here's a very short example of what I have:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newacronym{MOSFET}{MOSFET}{metal-oxide semiconductor field-effect transistor}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\Gls{MOSFET}}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30167/suppress-the-glossary-expansion-at-first-occurance) is related, but doesn't really do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{\let\gls\glsfirst
\let\Gls\Glsfirst
\tableofcontents}
```

will make it use the expanded form in the title and the toc

Comment: That's nice! I see the braces are essential.

Comment: @davidcarlisle is there anyway of not expanding in TOC or titles. The think is otherwise the first time in text is not expanded. For instance, one in toc if I talk about a term in the introduction it is not expanded. Should I use \glsresetall{}?

Answer (score 4):

David's answer works fine because your MWE has the location list suppressed (`nonumberlist`) and doesn't use `hyperref`. However I thought I'd better add this in case others have a similar problem but need a more general solution that works with the number list and `hyperref`.

In general [it's best not to use commands like `\Gls` in chapter/section headings](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#whynoglsinsection). There's more of a problem than just prematurely triggering the first use flag. It will also cause the table of contents to be added to the entry's location list, which isn't particularly helpful to the reader, and can cause nested hyperlinks and problems with PDF bookmarks. Depending on the page style, you can also end up indexing the entry on every page that the chapter/section title appears in the page header.

If you're happy to extend the `glossaries` package with [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), then a better approach is to use commands like `\glsfmtshort`, `\glsfmtlong` or `\glsfmtfull` in the chapter/section heading. For example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc=false]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{MOSFET}{MOSFET}{metal-oxide semiconductor field-effect
transistor}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{\Glsfmtfull{MOSFET}}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

See also [Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:headtitle).

Comment: What is the difference to `\acrfull{MOSEFET}` of glossaries?

Comment: @YAK `\acrfull` (and `\acrshort`, `\acrlong` etc) are designed for the base `glossaries` package's acronym mechanism. `\glsxtrfull` (`\glsxtrshort`, `\glsxtrlong` etc) are designed for `glossaries-extra`'s abbreviation mechanism which allows different abbreviation styles. The base commands won't reflect the change in style. Commands like `\glsfmtfull` (`\Glsfmtfull`, `\glsfmtshort` etc) are specifically designed for use in section headings.

Comment: So `glossaries-extra` is not required to solve the OP's problem but if used `\glossaries-extra` is?

Comment: @YAK `\chapter{\Glsfmtfull{MOSFET}}` (from `glossaries-extra`) is the best solution. With just the base `glossaries` package, the least problematic solution is `\chapter{\Glsentryfull{MOSFET}}` or (with `hyperref`) `\chapter{\texorpdfstring{\Glsentryfull{MOSFET}}{\glsentrylong{MOSFET} (\glsentryshort{MOSFET})}}`.