# Glossary terms appear in full in the list of figures

Tags: glossaries

I am using the command gls to create a glossary at the beginning of my thesis. However if I use the command for example in the caption of a figure environment, then the only time the full text together with its acronym appears only in the list of figures.

This then entails that the first time I use gls for a term in the main body of the thesis, only the acronym appears in the compiled version....

Is there a way to get around this issue??

Comment: Possibly related to [How not to expand acronym in toc or section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-not-to-expand-acronym-in-toc-or-section-title). You can use `\glsresetall` after `\listoffigures` but beware of nested hyperlinks if you use `hyperref`.

Comment: See also [Why shouldn't I use commands like \gls in \section, \chapter, \caption etc?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#whynoglsinsection).

Comment: While I have no reason to think it will take care of glossaries, the `notoccite` package fixes similar problems when using `\cite`s inside of figure captions.  You might try it just to see.

Answer (score 6):

I've found this to be the quickest solution for me:

```
\begin{document}
[...]
\glsunsetall
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\glsresetall
[...]
\end{document}
```

The commands `\glsunsetall` and `\glsresetall` have the function to set or reset the so-called *first use flag*.
With the sequence I've written, acronyms in the LoF and LoT are in the short form.
Then, thanks to `\glsresetall`, they are displayed correctly in the text (*first use* first, and then the short form).

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have something like this:

```
\newacronym{ex}{EX}{Example X}
```

You can use `\caption[ex]{\gls{ex}}`.
This way, the actual caption shown in List of Figures doesn't invoke glossaries.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestion in the other answer, you can use `\glsentryshort` instead of `\gls` in the caption:

```
\caption{An example \glsentryshort{sample}}
```

Another option is to use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) which provides commands like `\glsfmtshort` which are designed to work in captions and section headings. This has the advantage over `\glsentryshort` in that it includes the font change for styles that set the abbreviation in a particular font. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-sc}
\newacronym{sample}{short-form}{long-form}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Sample}
First use: \gls{sample}.

Next use: \gls{sample}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
Insert figure here.
\caption{An example \glsfmtshort{sample}}
\end{figure}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If you prefer the long form, you can use `\glsfmtlong` instead, or the full form with `\glsfmtfull`.