# Is it possible to use \acrfull \acrshort in the \subsection etc commands

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I use the `\acrfull` `\acrshort` commands. Sometimes I also used them in the `\section`, `\subsection` etc. commands. Now I get the warning:

`Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing '\acrfull'`

Is it possible to get rid of this message and that the correct string is shown in the pdf?

Comment: Have you checked https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53513/82917 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10555/82917?

Comment: Not yet, but it seems to work.

Comment: Nicola's answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74730/how-to-tweak-expansion-of-glossary-entry-in-section-chapter-title-and-toc may be helpful in your understanding (though it does not get rid of the warning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`glossaries` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glslink) warns against using commands like `\acrfull` in section and caption commands.

> I strongly recommend that you don’t use the commands defined in this
>   chapter in the arguments of sectioning or caption commands or any
>   other command that has a moving argument.
>
> Aside from problems with expansion issues, PDF bookmarks and possible
>   nested hyperlinks in the table of contents (or list of whatever) any
>   use of the commands described in §6.1 The `\gls`-Like Commands (First
>   Use Flag Queried) will have their first use flag unset when they
>   appear in the table of contents (or list of whatever).
>
> The above warning is particularly important if you are using the
>   `glossaries` package in conjunction with the `hyperref` package. Instead,
>   use one of the expandable commands listed in §9 Using Glossary Terms
>   Without Links (such as `\glsentrytext` but not the non-expandable case
>   changing versions like `\Glsentrytext`). Alternatively, provide an
>   alternative via the optional argument to the sectioning/caption
>   command or use `hyperref`’s `\texorpdfstring`. Examples:
>
> ```
> \chapter{An overview of \glsentrytext{perl}}  
> \chapter[An overview of Perl]{An overview of \gls{perl}}  
> \chapter{An overview of \texorpdfstring{\gls{perl}}{Perl}}
> ```
>
> If you want to retain the formatting that’s available through commands
>   like `\acrshort` (for example, if you are using one of the small caps
>   styles), then you might want to consider the `glossaries-extra` package
>   which provides commands for this purpose.

So with just the base `glossaries` package, you need something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[\glsentrylong{html} (\glsentryshort{html})]{\acrfull{html}}

\acrshort{html}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This ensures expandable content for the PDF bookmarks and avoids nested hyperlinks in the table of contents.

With the `glossaries-extra` extension package, you can use one of the commands listed in [4. Entries in Sectioning Titles, Headers, Captions and Contents](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:headtitle). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\glsfmtfull{html}}

\glsxtrshort{html}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Note that commands like `\glsfmtfull` don't index or form a hyperlink but they do honour the abbreviation style and they use `\texorpdfstring` to provide a version for the PDF bookmarks. Compare this with `\acrfull` which indexes and creates a hyperlink, which means with `\section{\acrfull{html}}` the entry in the table of contents ends up indexed, as well as every page with the section title in the header.

Note that with `glossaries-extra`, you can use the `short` abbreviation style if you don't want the full form on first use, which means you can use the shorter `\gls` rather than the longer `\glsxtrshort`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short}
\newacronym{html}{HTML}{hypertext markup language}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\glsfmtfull{html}}

\gls{html}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The full form can be obtained with `\glsxtrfull` in normal text and `\glsfmtfull` in section and caption commands.