# How to tweak expansion of acro entry in section/chapter title and ToC?

Tags: expansion, acro

Same question as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74730/how-to-tweak-expansion-of-glossary-entry-in-section-chapter-title-and-toc) but regarding the `acro` package.

How shall I prevent expansion in section, title and ToC?

[image]

MWE

```
%\documentclass{book} 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{acro} 

\DeclareAcronym{asset}{% 
    short=asset, 
    long= underlying asset, 
}

\DeclareAcronym{assetclass}{% 
    short=asset class, 
    long=asset class, 
} 

\begin{document} 

%\acresetall
\tableofcontents

%\chapter{\Ac{asset} vs \ac{assetclass}}

\section{Don't get confused between \ac{asset} and  \ac{assetclass}}

This is the demonstration of the usage of \ac{asset}---which is not to be confused with \ac{assetclass}. 

\printacronyms 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the starred commands, `\Ac*`

Comment: Merci ! My bad, I did spot this useful feature in your very well written doc !
I'll post the answer to save you time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a comment from the author of the package, everything is easier :)

Problem solved with the "star" version of `\ac*` `\Ac*`, `\Acs`, etc commands

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{acro} 

\DeclareAcronym{asset}{% 
    short=asset, 
    long= underlying asset, 
}

\DeclareAcronym{assetclass}{% 
    short=asset class, 
    long=asset class, 
} 

\begin{document} 

%\acresetall
\tableofcontents

\section{Don't get confused between \acs*{asset} and  \acs*{assetclass}}

This is the demonstration of the usage of \ac{asset}---which is not to be confused with \ac{assetclass}. 

\printacronyms 

\end{document}
```